# UNRESOLVED: Pushing oil out of a tank using work integration

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, physics, applications

I have a tank of oil with a density of $900\frac{kg}{m^3}$. My tank has a spout that is $2$ meters tall and the general radius of the tank is $6$ meters. It is half full of oil and I want to find the work required to pump all that oil out. In this case we use $9.8\frac{m}{s^2}$ for the force of gravity.

[image: Tank of Oil]

My initial approach to this problem was to find the work required to pump oil out of the sphere and then add that work to the work required to pump the oil out of the spout. But I realized I could not determine the radius of the spout to do so.

So so far I said that to find the $ x = r \ $ I must take $c^2 = 6^2 + 6^2$ which equals $c = 6\sqrt{2}$ then find x by saying:
$$ 
72 = x^2+y^2 \\
x^2 = 72 - y^2 \\
x = \sqrt{72-y^2} \\
x = 6\sqrt{2} - y
$$

So I have my change in radius, $x$. Now I find the volume of the oil, which is $8820\pi(72-12\sqrt{2}+y^2)\Delta y$. I have my force and my distance I say is $(8-y)$ which is $6 + 2$ if I say the center of the sphere is the point of origin.

I then integrate this by $W = \int F*d$. So:
$$
W = \int_{-6}^0 8820\pi(72-12\sqrt{2}+y^2)(8-y)\Delta y \\
W = 8820\pi\int_{-6}^0 (72-12\sqrt{2}+y^2)(8-y) \ dy \\
W = 8820\pi\int_{-6}^0 (576-72y-96\sqrt{2}+12\sqrt{2}y+8y^2-y^3) \ dy
$$

I integrated it and plugged in values but kept getting the wrong answer. So my logic has been to push the oil from its floor to its half point. And also my distance in the work formula has been from the top of the spout to the surface of the oil which is $y$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Two minor observations:  It is not true that $\sqrt{72 - y^2} = 6\sqrt{2} - y$ unless $y = 0$.  Notice that if $y = 6$, then $\sqrt{72 - y^2} = \sqrt{72 - 36} = \sqrt{36} = 6$, while $6\sqrt{2} - y = 6\sqrt{2} - 6 = 6(\sqrt{2} - 1)$.  Also, $9.8~\text{m}/\text{s}^2$ is the acceleration due to gravity.  The force due to gravity is $F = mg$, which has units of $\text{N} = \text{kg} \cdot \text{m}/\text{s}^2$.

Comment: Where N is F? Newtons is force?

Comment: Correct.  The unit of force is the Newton.

Comment: Well anyway, I decided to find the hypotenuse so that I can find the value x where x is not a constant. Are you saying it was wrong to have done that?

Comment: Let $z$ be our vertical axis.  If we set $z = 0$ at the center of the tank, the radius of the horizontal cross-section at height $z$ is $\sqrt{36 - z^2}$.  To see this, draw a radius from the center to the sphere to the point where the cross-section at height $z$ intersects the tank.  This yields a right-triangle with hypotenuse $6$ and vertical leg $|z|$.  The horizontal leg (the radius of the cross-section) is then $\sqrt{6^2 - |z|^2} = \sqrt{36 - z^2}$ by the Pythagorean Theorem.

Comment: how can z be equal to $36-z^2$, there aren't enough variables in this equation

Comment: I did not say that $z$ is equal to $36 - z^2$.  I said that that the radius of the cross-section at height $z$ is $\sqrt{36 - z^2}$.  The radius is perpendicular to the $z$-axis.

Comment: Do we agree that $x = 36-z^2$ if $x$ is the radius?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The radius of the spout doesn't matter at all.  You just need to lift all the oil to the height of the top of the spout.  Let $z$ be the vertical axis, positive upward, with $0$ at the center of the tank.  The work required is then $$W=\int_V 9.8\rho(8-z)dV$$because a small element of volume $dV$ needs to be lifted $8-z$ against gravity.  Now you can use the disk method for a solid of revolution to do the integral.

Using the disk method, at a particular $z$ we have a circle of radius $\sqrt{36-z^2}$ which needs to be lifted $8-z$ to get out of the tank.  The work is then $$\int_{-6}^0 9.8\rho (8-z) \pi(36-z^2)dz$$

Comment: Is v the volume in this case? What is the upper limit of integration? And is this integrated added to another integrated to provide the work of both spout and sphere?

Comment: Why wouldn't the radius of the spout matter? Theoretically, a larger radius spout would yield less work than a smaller spout. So we must take into account more than just the height of the spout? If not then just have the spout be flat against the top of the sphere as just a hole for the fluid to exit?

Comment: We are ignoring friction, so all that matters is how high we lift the oil. We have to lift it to the top of the spout, so the height matters. The (corrected) 8 in my answer is the $z$ of the top. The diameter of the spout doesn't enter

Comment: For this problem I am getting the same answer I did in my original approach

Comment: [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+9.8(8-z)pi(36-z%5E2)+from+-6+to+0) gives $45442.5 \rho$ for the answer