# Find hypotenuse of a sphere given radius.

Tags: calculus, geometry, trigonometry, physics

Say I have a circle of radius 6 ft. How do I know that my hypotenuse is also 6ft?

It makes sense to me that from a point of origin $(0,0)$ on the circle, the x-axis and y-axis both stop at $6$ft.

So when finding the hypotenuse we say that the hypotenuse, $c^2=6^2+6^2$. So c cannot possibly be 6?

I am asking because I want to find x, the horizontal interval, where it is not a constant i.e. place my newfound c into the equation, $x^2 = c^2 - y^2$, where $c$ is defined as a constant and both $x$ and $y$ are not.

Comment: What is the hypotenuse of a sphere?

Comment: What hypotenuse?  A right triangle has a hypotenuse, a sphere doesn't.

Comment: When I say sphere I mean a circle. So imagine a radius of a circle that starts from a point on the circumference to the center. And another perpendicular line going directly down and then a 3rd line connecting those two points on the circumference to create a right triangle within the circle.

Comment: The idea is two of the lines will be the same length since they derive from the very center of the circle but the 3rd line, the connecting hypotenuse line will not be exactly the same length because we would have to solve for it?

Comment: You need to use the Pythagorean Theorem: $x^2+y^2=z^2$ but in this case you have $x=y=r$, so $2r^2=z^2$. So $z$ will be a fixed multiple of $r$. Can you finish?

Comment: yes $z^2=72$, I have gotten this many times over. I want to rewrite $x$ as $x=\sqrt{36-y^2}$ But the square root happens to be $6\sqrt{2}$ not $36$

Comment: So see, my reason for wanting the hypotenuse is to apply it to x, where x changes with respect to y where y is vertical height. As it would make sense for a spherical tank for example.

Comment: I think I see what is confusing you. If $(x,y)$ represents the coordinates of a point of the circle, then $x^2+y^2=36$. But if you think of $x$ and $y$ as the lengths of the two sides of the right triangle inside the circle, then those are **different** from coordinates $(x,y)$. For those interpretations of $x$ and $y$ it is the case, from the Pythagorean theorem, that $x^2+y^2=72$.

Comment: I'm still not following.. See my post on what this post is in reference to to get a better understanding of what I am achieve. Look at the image in it and note that I am trying to find the instantaneous value of r. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2344595/unresolved-pushing-oil-out-of-a-tank-using-work-integration

Comment: I don't see a link to another post.

Comment: Sorry see above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gather that you are trying to understand Ross Millikan's answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2344595/unresolved-pushing-oil-out-of-a-tank-using-work-integration) about the work done when oil is lifted out of a spherical tank.

A reason for your confusion is that you are drawing the wrong diagram.  Consider the diagram below:

[image: sphere_with_cross-section]

The circle with radius $r_c$ is a cross-section of a sphere with radius $r_s$ at a distance of $|z|$ from the center.  By the Pythagorean Theorem,
$$r_c^2 + |z|^2 = r_s^2$$
Since the square of a real number is the square of its absolute value,
$$r_c^2 + z^2 = r_s^2$$
Solving for $r_c$ yields
\begin{align*}
r_c^2 & = r_s^2 - z^2\\
r_c & = \sqrt{r_s^2 - z^2}
\end{align*}
In that problem, the sphere has radius $6$, so the radius of the cross-section is 
$$r_c = \sqrt{36 - z^2}$$
Therefore, the area of the cross-section is 
$$A = \pi r_c^2 = \pi\left(\sqrt{36 - z^2}\right)^2 = \pi(36 - z^2)$$
Thus, the integral
$$V = \int_{-6}^{0} \pi(36 - z^2)~\text{dz}$$
yields the volume of the oil in the bottom half of the sphere.  Multiplying by the density $\rho$ of the oil yields the mass 
$$m = \int_{-6}^{0} \rho\pi(36 - z^2)dz$$
of the oil.  The work done to lift the oil out of the sphere is 
$$W = \int_{-6}^{0} 9.8\rho(8 - z)\pi(36 - z^2)dz$$
where $9.8~\text{m}/\text{s}^2$ is the upward acceleration against gravity and $8 - z$ is the distance oil at a height $z$ is lifted to reach the top of the spout.

Comment: Thank you. You are awesome.